# Web push notification are not working in react native WebView

Tags: react-native, webview, push-notification

I have implemented web share API and notification *(using Firebase Cloud Messaging)*.

Here is the code:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
      <WebView
         source={{ uri: "https://examplepwa.firebaseapp.com" }}
      />
 </View>
```

**Expected behavior:**
PWA is working perfectly in the Chrome browser but in WebView it doesn't work. How to support these features in WebView?

Tried to inject javascript but not working.